# I want to make dropdown text field with suggestion list, How can I make this

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make dropdown text field with suggestion list, How can I make this, please describe me

```
Expanded(
                          child: new TextField(
                        controller: _controller,
                        // decoration: InputDecoration(
                      )),
                      new PopupMenuButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                        onSelected: (value) {
                          _controller.text = value as String;
                        },
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return _loadedPacks.map<PopupMenuItem>((value) {
                            return new PopupMenuItem(
                                child: new Text(value["package_name"]),
                                value: value["package_name"]);
                          }).toList();
                        },
                      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this by the following 2 options:

1. Create your own AutoComplete Textfield using `Autocomplete` widget. Ref: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html
2. You can use `flutter_typeahead` pub. Ref: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead

Note: You can find the usage of both options in the link